# Excel Sumifs Formula to 3 Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hey I have `SUMIFS` formula that I built to 3 columns separately (each month data is in a different column). How can I make this formula shorter? Any ideas?
I have 2 criterias and I want to sum everything that is right in each of the 3 columns. I want somehow to get all the data from column U to W.

> =SUMIFS(OldConversion!U:U,OldConversion!H:H,Level!$R$1,OldConversion!A:A,Level!A2) + SUMIFS(OldConversion!V:V,OldConversion!H:H,Level!$R$1,OldConversion!A:A,Level!A2) + SUMIFS(OldConversion!W:W,OldConversion!H:H,Level!$R$1,OldConversion!A:A,Level!A2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMPRODUCT like below:

`=SUMPRODUCT(OldConversion!U:W*(OldConversion!H:H=Level!$R$1)*(OldConversion!A:A=Level!A2))`

> **Note** Avoid complete column references as they will add calculation overhead.

Comment: As far as I know `SUMPRODUCT` (along with `SUMIF(S)` and `COUNTIF(S)`) is actually great at knowing when to stop looping (i.e. when it gets to the end of the used range). You still need to be careful with CSE array formulas though.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov interesting. I had tested it on a small dataset before posting.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I copued the formula as is. it is still value error.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov does your data contain error value somewhere? My test file can be accessed here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwaztkjh89m5ga4/stackoverflow_49364026.xlsx?dl=0